# Solving the following SDE with a constant

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Given is the stochastic differential equation:

$\frac{dX(t)}{X(t)}=\mu+\sigma \theta dt+ \sigma dW(t)$, where $W(t)$ is the standard Wiener process and $X(0)=x_0$

I try to solve this by the Itos formula by setting $f=log(X(t))$ and then taking the Itos differential:

$d log (X(t)) = \frac{1}{X(t)}dX(t)-\frac{1}{2 X(t)^2}dX(t)^2$.

Im wondering if this is the right way to go? Since I know that this will be a messy calculation in that case.
Also, the constant $\mu$, how should I look at it when integrating on both sides?

Thank you

Thank you

Comment: As written your equation makes no sense. Perhaps you mean $dX/X=(\mu+\sigma \theta) dt + \sigma dW$.

Comment: According to this article, https://cermics.enpc.fr/reports/CERMICS-2003/CERMICS-2003-256.pdf page 6, equation (21), they use the equation above. I assume then that there is a typo in the article?

Comment: Yes, I think there should be parentheses there, especially since they've already been using $\mu$ as part of a drift previously.

Comment: OK. Just of curiosity. If there were no paranthesis, why would the equation not make sense? (My Stochastic calculus knowledge is limited)

Comment: Heuristically, the left side should be infinitely small, and so should the right side, but $\mu$ is not infinitely small. More rigorously you can write down the integral form of the SDE, which is really the definition of the SDE (but we frequently don't write it that way for brevity's sake). The SDE $dX=\mu dt + \sigma dW$ is understood as $X(t)-X(0)=\int_0^t \mu ds + \int_0^t \sigma dW_s$. There is no way to make this conversion if not every term in the SDE has a differential in it.

Comment: Ok, but in that case this is much much easier to solve :). Thank you!